# File Uploading to Google Drive

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api

I am just starting with the Google Drive API. The [quick start](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/ruby) is quite handy, but it only explains file listing feature.

Cannot find the file upload feature in the [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#python) page.

The RI documentation for `Google::Apis` only contains hundreds of new line characters (1128 to be specific), and nothing interesting.

How do I upload files to google drive using the Ruby API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/docs/media-upload.md) are two upload examples using Drive V2 (one resumable, one not), and [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/DriveV3/DriveService#create_file-instance_method) you can see the method you should be using in V3 (`create_file` instead of `insert_file`), as well as an explanation of all the possible parameters you can provide.

The first example could be written in V3 like this:

```
drive_service.create_file({title: 'My Favorite Movie'}, upload_source: 'mymovie.m4v',
                  content_type: 'video/mp4')
```

#### Reference:

- [Class: Google::Apis::DriveV3](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/DriveV3)
- [create_file](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/DriveV3/DriveService#create_file-instance_method)

Comment: This kind of works, but the file is always uploaded with the title "Untitled"